# Line integral circle 3d parameterization

Tags: calculus, contour-integration, parametrization

Let $F=(-2y,-z,2x)$.

Let $\partial D$ be a boundary of the intersection of:
$$D=\{x,y,z: x+y+z=2\}\cap\{x,y,z:x^2+y^2+z^2=4 \}$$

Need to find $$\oint_{\partial D}\vec{F}$$
Naturally, this problem is solved by Stokes theorem, but I wanted to do so with standard parameterization.

$$ x=2,y=0,z=0 \\
x=0,y=2, z=0 \\
x=0,y=0,z=2$$
These three points exist on said circle, so we can find it's centre.

Let $a,b,c$ be the centre of said circle, then
$$ (2-a)^2+(0-b)^2+(0-c)^2= \\(0-a)^2+(2-b)^2+(0-c)^2=\\(0-a)^2+(0-b)^2+(2-c)^2$$
Solving this gives us $a=b=c$
After putting $a+a+a=2$ we find that the circle centre is $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3})$

We can easily find the radius now.

Now let's find the parameterization for the circle with $$\partial D(t)= (x(t),y(y),z(t))$$

In 2d, such parameterization would be $(a+r\cos(t),b+r\sin(t))$

According to a video on youtube, this time the parameterization will be: $$
x(t)=c_1+a_1r\cos(t)+b_1r\sin(t)\\
y(t)=c_2+a_2r\cos(t)+b_2r\sin(t)\\
z(t)=c_3+a_3r\cos(t)+b_3r\sin(t)$$
Where $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ is the circle centre and $A,B$ are some projection vectors.

I tried finding them but couldn't figure how.

Assuming $(2,0,0) $ is the starting location for our integral and $t\in [ 0,2\pi]$ then we get
$$ 2= \frac{2}{3} + a_1 r \\
 0=\frac{2}{3} + a_2 r \\
0= \frac{2}{3} + a_3 r $$

Now I can find $A$ but not sure how to obtain B, as I can't just use any point.
Would appreciate guidance to find that vector, or how to find $ A,B$ systematically and not just putting points.

Comment: You just need any two orthogonal unit vectors in the given plain

Comment: So just taking $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(2,-2,0)$ and $B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} (2,0,-2)$ will work?

Comment: I don't see these vectors in x+y+z=2

Comment: Why not? the points $(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2)$ are there.or do I need to Gram Schmidt them for orthogonality?

Comment: sorry the are on the plain but not orthogonal